# Issue with Importing xls file to sql server 2008 using c#

Tags: c#, xls

I am doing the task of importing xls file to sql server 2008 using c#, the xls file contains 3
column (ProductCode = having alphanumeric values,Productname = having string values,
Categoryids = having alphanumeric values) in xls file.

When I am importing the xls through my code it reads Productname,Categoryids but ProductCode with only numeric values, it can not read the codes which containing  characters.

eg : sample column values
**productcode**
-30-sunscreen-250ml,
04 5056,
045714PC,
10-cam-bag-pouch-navy-dot,
100102

I reads 100102, but it can not reads the [045714PC,04 5056,-30-sunscreen-250ml,10-cam-bag-pouch-navy-dot]

Please suggest any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel's OLEDB driver makes assumptions about the column's data based on the first 8 rows of data. If the *majority* of the first 8 rows for a given column, it assumes the entire column is numeric and then can't properly handle the alphanumeric values.

There are four solutions for this:

1. Sort your incoming data so the majority of the first 8 rows have alphanumeric values in that column (and in any other column with mixed numeric / alphanumeric data).
2. Add rows of fake data in, say, rows 2-9 that you ignore when you actually perform the import, and ensure that row contains letters in any column that should not be strictly numeric.
3. Edit the REG_DWORD key called "TypeGuessRows" located at  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel] in your registry and change the 8 to a 0. This will force Excel to look through the entire sheet before guessing the column data types. However, this can hinder performance. (You can also change the value from 8 to anything between 1 and 16, but that just changes how many rows Excel looks at, and 16 may still not be enough for you.)
4. Add ";IMEX=1" in your connection string. This will change the logic to look for **at least one** non-numeric value instead of looking at the **majority** of the values. This may then be combined with solution (1) or (2) to ensure it "sees" an alphanumeric value in the appropriate columns within the first 8 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your important reply.

Comment: If my answer works for you, please tick the checkbox to accept it as the right answer. That is how this site is supposed to work...